# Solaris: FTP Server: listen on single IP (daemonaddress option in /etc/ftpd/ftpaccess?)

Tags: ftp, solaris, listener

I am attempting to lock down the ftp server to listen on a specific interface instead of all interfaces. I added this line to the end of `/etc/ftpd/ftpaccess`

```
daemonaddress   192.168.x.x
```

The I ran `svcadm restart ftp`

But the server is still listening on `192.168.y.y`

Any ideas? I read from `man ftpaccess` that this only works in standalone mode, but I can't figure out what that is or how to use it.

Comment: "standalone" probably means "not running under inetd" here (maybe inetd is even integrated into the svc stuff now? - haven't worked much with Solaris 10). If the ftpd process is only around when somebody is connected, you're not running in standalone mode. Generally, the software that comes with Solaris is usually a bit lacking, you would maybe have a better time with switching to e.g. proftpd.

Comment: This is a legacy setup based on Solaris 10 6/06, we will not be upgrading any software on these systems. Thank you for the information though. I do believe that you are correct about ftp running under inet. I will take a look from that angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [C. Ramseyer](https://serverfault.com/users/39165/c-ramseyer)'s comment, I found what I was looking for.

If found [some documentation for `/etc/inet/inetd.conf`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/utilities/i/inetd.conf.html) that described `addr` syntax, that looked promising.

Then I went to `inetd.conf` and it said to use `inetadm(1M)` (the new way).

I looked at `man inetadm` and under "EXAMPLES" I found the ability to `-m`odify a property for a service and another to `-l`ist properties on a service.

I looked at `inetadm -l ftp` and found `bind_addr`

**The solution is** to use `inetadm -m ftp bind_addr=192.168.x.x`